# Mapbox Navigation SDK, problem adding waypoints to a NavigationRoute.builder()

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

Currently i am trying to create a navigation route in the android navigation SDK provided by mapbox. The problem starts when adding more than one waypoint to the query. (the query below returns a response and draws the route on the map)

```
NavigationRoute.builder()
            .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
            .origin(start)
            .destination(end)
            .alternatives(false)
            .build()
            .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<DirectionsResponse> call, @NonNull Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        try {
                            assert response.body() != null;
                            routeodfgoh = response.body().routes().get(0);

                            if (navigationMapRoute != null) {
                                navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                            } else {
                                navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, map);
                            }

                            //how to draw the map think map matching is work
                            navigationMapRoute.addRoute(routeodfgoh);

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

However, the application requires that some query's have more than one waypoint added. after lots of searching i found this [mapbox-navigation-android add waypoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419893/mapbox-navigation-android-add-waypoints) which lead to the code below. however, the query never returns a response.

```
 NavigationRoute.Builder builder = NavigationRoute.builder()
            .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
            .origin(start)
            .destination(end);

    for (Point waypoint : coords) {
        builder.addWaypoint(waypoint);
    }

    builder.build()
            .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<DirectionsResponse> call, @NonNull Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {

           if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                try {
                    assert response.body() != null;
                    routeodfgoh = response.body().routes().get(0);

                    if (navigationMapRoute != null) {
                        navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                    } else {
                        navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, map);
                    }

                    //how to draw the map think map matching is work
                    navigationMapRoute.addRoute(routeodfgoh);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

any ideas as to why i don't get a response would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default profile is `PROFILE_DRIVING_TRAFFIC` which has a limit of 3 coordinates. If you update this to `PROFILE_DRIVING`, using `.profile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_DRIVING)`, that should solve the coordinate limit issue.

Comment: The throwable shows i'm adding too many coordinates,The max allowed is 3 according to the throwable. The documentation it says allows up to 25 waypoints to be added including origin and destination. am i using this class incorrectly? if so, what do i need to do to create a Navigation route with 25 waypoints?